# Is it possible to add multiple items to a dictionary?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, database, postgresql

how can I add the sum of every column in a Dictionary?

[image]

I would like to get this as result:

```
{
"collateral_amount": "600000", //The total sum of the collateral_amount column
"id": "10", //The total sum of the id column
"withdraw_collateral": "30000", //The total sum of tthe withdraw_collateral column
"total_amount": "90000" //The total sum of the total_amount
}
```

```
        public async Task<StatsDomain[]> GetStats()
        {
            var items = new Dictionary<string, long?>();
            var sqlStatement = "SELECT borrower, id, collateral_amount, withdraw_amount, total_amount_to_treasure FROM table";
            var queryResult = await _databaseConnection.QueryAsync<StatsModel>(sqlStatement);

            foreach (var row in queryResult)
            {
                if (items.ContainsKey(row.Borrower))
                {
                    items[row.Borrower] += row.CollateralAmount;
                    items[row.Borrower] += row.WithdrawAmount;
                    items[row.Borrower] += row.TotalAmountToTreasure;
                }
                else
                {
                    items.Add(row.Borrower, row.CollateralAmount);
                    items.Add(row.Borrower, row.WithdrawAmount);
                    items.Add(row.Borrower, row.TotalAmountToTreasure);
                }
            }
            return items.Select(item => new StatsDomain(item.Value, item.Value, item.Value, item.Value, item.Value, item.Value)).ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: Why not just do the `SUM` in the `SELECT` query?

Comment: Hey @DStanley! The reason for why I don't use the SUM function is because I need the last id (6 in this case) and I need to make a condition where if the withdraw_amount and collateral_amount are null that means the loan is active if not is non-active. Thats why I didn't do it in the query

Answer (score 0):

You could add the desired functionality to your `StatsModel`

```
class StatsModel
{
    public StatsModel(decimal collateral, decimal withdraw)
    {
        Collateral = collateral;
        Withdraw = withdraw;
    }

    public decimal Collateral { get; }
    public decimal Withdraw { get; }
    public decimal Total => Collateral + Withdraw;
}
```